# Show type alias contents instead of type alias name in tooltip

Tags: typescript

I have a set of exported functions in a typescript library that use the same input:

```js
type MyInput=string | number;

export function func1(input: MyInput): void {}
export function func2(input: MyInput): void {}
```

The problem is that when these functions are exported to library users, the autocompletion shows the input required to be `MyInput`, which is correct, but not as helpful as `string | number`.

Is there a way to force the exported type to be the "resolved" type instead of the alias `MyInput` whilst avoiding duplicating `string | number` on every function?

Ideally, the types exported I'm looking for should look the same as the following :

```js
export function func1(input: string | number): void {}
export function func2(input: string | number): void {}
```

Comment: It can be useful to also export the `MyInput` type so downstream you can do `import type { MyInput } from 'mylib'; const a: MyInput = isMaybe ? 'foo' : 123; func2(a)`. In which case, leaving that as an explicit `MyInput` may be preferable.

Comment: What happens if you `export type MyInput`?

Comment: Exporting `MyInput` allows users to use that type to define the variables (as @AlexWayne mentions) however, the desire output is to completely hide that variable from the users, including in the function signature

Answer (score 0):

don't think there's a good way to reliably get what you want. It's kind of up to typescript which types they decide to show. But you can play around with things until you get the result you want.

In this case particularly, it seems if you write `MyInput` as

```
type MyInput=[string, number][number] //still string | number
```

Then it will show the union rather than Alias.

So probably this works for other cases where you want to use a union as a function arg. For other situations will need to see if you find other tricks, always good to play around with different ways of representing the same thing to see if you can modify the result.

Here's a link to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggvAbQM7AE4EsB2BzANFTAVwFsAjCVAXQSLIsoCgnRIoAhOFDHAH1vNRMGEAB5gA9qmBQAZoUwBjYOnGZZ8hQEYAFFjCFgALlgBKYwDdx6ACZQA3gF9hYydLmLlq9YoBMuzPpG7GZQljb2DlBM7lraAORxJlAA9MlQXFjYUDwEJAIMMX4JSanszODQAMJQcFDIaJl8efQ0zVQMCqoosgDMNVD%20gYaVJnAAfI4FPfGJKWkAhgA2SOLpDTjZuXSoQA)

Comment: This is good advice, I'll try different options. `[string, number][number]` in particular didn't seem to work though

Comment: yea I think it can vary from ts version to version. Works on the playground link thought yea? Maybe can find a more reliable solution with some either type wrapper or fn wrapper that takes the args using `Parameters` and  `ReturnType` to do some ts transform on the types.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work in the playground for me :(
Probably depends on some versions as you say